# Using aggregate in R to retrieve list value

Tags: r, aggregate

The code `aggregate(df$var, list(df$id), runs.test)` returns the test statistic (standard normal) of the variance of a given function.

Normally, the code `runs.test(data)$p.value` gives you the p-value. But `aggregate(df$var, list(df$id), runs.test(df$var)$p.value)` gives the the error:

```
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  'runs.test(df$var)$p.value' is not a function, character or symbol
```

How can I use `aggregate` to give me the p-value?

Comment: a reproducible example would be nice. But you might try `aggregate(df$var, list(df$id), function(x) runs.test(x)$p.value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to declare an anonymous function.

```
aggregate(var ~ id, data = df, FUN = function(x) runs.test(x)$p.value)
```

By the way, when you use functions that are not `base R` functions like `runs.test`, always include a call to `library(pkgname)` as the first line of code.